# Exception of type 'System.FormatException' on double.Parse

Tags: c#, exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Jumps to this code right after

```
double parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
```

Nothing on textBox I'm supposed to input a number in the application

and I've tried Try.Parse and I get an error "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments"

which I have no clue what that means.

THis is the whole code

```
namespace Project03_18Mar15_Alan_Mederos_B
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void calculateTotalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double oil = 0, lube = 0, radiator = 0, trans = 0, inspection = 0; double muffler = 0,tire = 0;
        if (oilChangeBx.Checked == true)
        {
            oil = 26;
        }
        if (lubeJobBx.Checked == true)
        {
            lube = 18;
        }
        if (radiatorFlushBx.Checked == true)
        {
            radiator = 30;
        }
        if (transFlushBx.Checked == true)
        {
            trans = 80;
        }
        if (inspectionBx.Checked == true)
        {
            inspection = 15;
        }
        if (replaceMufflerBx.Checked == true)
        {
            muffler = 100;
        }
        if (tireRotationBx.Checked == true)
        {
            tire = 20;
        }


        // Convert all values to doubles
            double parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);   
            double labor = double.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
            double oillube = OilLubeCharges(oil, lube);
            double flush = FlushCharges(radiator, trans);
            double misc = MiscCharges(inspection, muffler, tire);
            double other = OtherCharges(parts, labor);
            double tax = TaxCharges(parts, labor, oillube, flush, misc, labor);
            double total = TotalCharges(oillube, flush, misc, other, tax);
            double services = oillube + flush + misc;
            servicesOutputLb.Text = services.ToString("c");
            partsOutputLb.Text = other.ToString("c");
            taxOutputLb.Text = tax.ToString("c");
            totalOutputLb.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }
    

    private double OilLubeCharges (double oil, double lube)
    {
        //return oil and lube charges
        return oil + lube;
    }
    private double FlushCharges(double radiator, double trans)
    {
    // returns radiator and transmission flush charges
        return radiator + trans;
    }
    private double MiscCharges(double inspection, double muffler, double tire)
    {
        //return inspection, muffler, and tire rotation charges
        return inspection + muffler + tire;

    }
   
    private double OtherCharges (double parts, double labor)
    {
        //return parts and labor
        return parts + labor;

    }
    
    private double TaxCharges (double parts, double labor, double oillube, 
        double flush, double misc, double other)
    { 
    //returns sales tax on parts only
        if (parts != 0 && labor != 0 && (oillube != 0
            && flush != 0 && misc != 0 && other != 0))
        {
            // sales on tax is 6%
            return (0.06 * parts);
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    private double TotalCharges(double oillube, double flush, 
        double misc, double other, double tax)
    {
        return oillube + flush + misc + other + tax;
    }

    private void clearBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clears all fields
        oilChangeBx.Checked = false;
        lubeJobBx.Checked = false;
        radiatorFlushBx.Checked = false;
        transFlushBx.Checked = false;
        inspectionBx.Checked = false;
        replaceMufflerBx.Checked = false;
        tireRotationBx.Checked = false;
        partsTextBox.Text = "";
        laborTextBox.Text = "";
        servicesOutputLb.Text = "";
        partsOutputLb.Text = "";
        taxOutputLb.Text = "";
        totalOutputLb.Text = "";
    }

    private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //exits form
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? There is also an example. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is in the text box when this happens? Nothing?

Comment: TryParse takes a string and an out param.  Create a double object and pass it in as an out param 'double result = 0;  if(double.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out result)) { }'

Comment: So is your question how to avoid the exception or how to use `TryParse`?

Comment: How do I avoid the exception, I just want to be able to use the form I created without this message showing up and not crashing my application

Answer (score 2):

The message "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments" is self explanatory.
You can only call TryParse with two or more parameters.

To use TryParse, with two parameters, you must pass the output variable as reference. See the code below:

```
double output;
bool success = double.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out output);
```

Pay atention, output must be passed initialized. If success, output will have value.

Other way is catching the exception:

```
double parts;

try
{ 
    parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
}
catch (FormatException fe)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Quantity of parts not informed");
}
```

EDIT2:

Look that in your code, you have two parsers:

```
        double parts = double.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);   
        double labor = double.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
```

And any of they can throw the FormatException. My sugestion is write something like that:

```
        double parts;
        double labor;
        if(
           double.TryParse(partsTextBox.Text, out parts)
           && double.TryParse(laborTextBox.Text, out labor))
        {
            double oillube = OilLubeCharges(oil, lube);
            double flush = FlushCharges(radiator, trans);
            double misc = MiscCharges(inspection, muffler, tire);
            double other = OtherCharges(parts, labor);
            double tax = TaxCharges(parts, labor, oillube, flush, misc, labor);
            double total = TotalCharges(oillube, flush, misc, other, tax);
            double services = oillube + flush + misc;
            servicesOutputLb.Text = services.ToString("c");
            partsOutputLb.Text = other.ToString("c");
            taxOutputLb.Text = tax.ToString("c");
            totalOutputLb.Text = total.ToString("c");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Quantity of parts and quantity of labors must be informed and must be valid!");
        }
```

Comment: I edited the answer and add how deal with exception.

Comment: If it helps I can send the whole code and see if there's anything I'm messing up anywhere else.

Comment: couldn't get that to go through

Comment: Whole code will be easier to see. Maybe the exception is not be throwing in this part of code. See this part of Double.TryParse documentation "


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



This overload differs from the Double.Parse(String) method by returning a Boolean value that indicates whether the parse operation succeeded instead of returning the parsed numeric value. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that s is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed."